# Subset sum variation: find the subset that sums to >= target, with minimum overshoot

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a set of positive integers, and a target sum **k**, find the subset that sums to exactly **k** or least exceeds **k**.  (i.e. equal or minimal overshoot)

This problem is occurring in a real life business feature-request, and the set size is expected to usually range from 1 to 30.  It has to be solvable by low-end-PCs within say 3 seconds, so I guesstimate that a bruteforce method probably couldn't handle much more than 10 input integers?

I've looked thru search hits related to subset sum and knapsack, but have not seen anyone discuss this >= variation yet.

Comment: It is rather easy to implement that variation, given you understand how the dynamic programming approach works.

Comment: See for example an answer on the *closest* subset https://stackoverflow.com/q/34188694/67579 . Yes the above accepts both overshooting and undershooting, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather simple extension of the original program: we simply use the dynamic programming algorithm, but also store lists we generate if these are overshooting the original value.

We can for example implement such algorithm as:

```
def least_gt_subset_sum(items, k):
    vals = [None]*(k+1)
    vals[0] = ()
    best_v = None
    best_k = 0
    for item in items:
        for i in range(k-1, -1, -1):
            if vals[i] is not None:
                if i + item <= k and vals[i+item] is None:
                    vals[i+item] = (*vals[i], item)
                if i + item > k and (best_v is None or i + item < best_v):
                    best_v = i + item
                    best_k = (*vals[i], item)
    if vals[k] is not None:
        return vals[k]
    else:
        return best_k
```

So here we use the same trick, but in case the value is higher than `k`, we do some bookkeeping, and store the best result. At the end, we look if there is a value that matches exactly, if not, we return the best set that was higher, otherwise we return the one that was exact.